# JavaScript array of object find property values if/Else if condition

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

I've an array of object and check for property values and based on it i need to perform some operation

```js
const arr= [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Skoda - Auto",
        "operation": "ADD"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "BMW - Auto",
        "operation": "DELETE"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Mustang",
        "operation": "DELETE"
    }
]

 if (arr.some(e => e.operation === 'ADD')) {
  console.log('will do some operation if its add')
 }
 else if(arr.some(e => e.operation === 'DELETE')) {
 console.log('will do some operation if its delete')
 }
 else {}
```

I tried the above way but it just does not enter else if block, not sure what wrong I'm doing, can someone plz help on this

Comment: There simply is no case where it passes both the `if` and the `else if`. Please explain what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: How can I make it pass through both basically check for the `operation` property if ADD to this DELETE to that

Comment: There is no item in your array that has an `operation` value different than `"ADD"` or `"Delete"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're actually looking for is a simple loop that does a check [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) item `car` in your array `arr`. [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) checks whether any item in your array matches a given condition.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Skoda - Auto",
    operation: "ADD"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "BMW - Auto",
    operation: "DELETE"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Mustang",
    operation: "DELETE"
  }
];

arr.forEach(car => {
  if (car.operation === "ADD") {
    console.log("will do some operation if its add");
  } else if (car.operation === "DELETE") {
    console.log("will do some operation if its delete");
  } else {
    // implementation
  }
});
```